# Hive in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

We have scala Jar file which is running on on-prem Hadoop cluster. It create hive tables on parquet file and do further spark processing on hive table.

May I know your suggestion on how to run such hive based spark processing in synapses spark pool? If possible, without changing our code?

Answer (score 0):

> Currently Spark only works with external Hive tables and non-transactional/non-ACID managed Hive tables. It doesn’t support Hive ACID/transactional tables now.

For more details, refer to [Use external Hive Metastore for Synapse Spark Pool (Preview）](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-external-metastore)